# How to give permission to share folder in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, shared-directory

I have made a folder `share`, when I shared this folder and access it from window 7 it gives an alert box `that you have no permission` only folder show `"share"` when go inside this folder then it alert appear.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT -> This is probably the easiest:

http://www.7tutorials.com/how-access-ubuntu-shared-folders-windows-7

Turn on guest access before playing with permissions to check it works

---

EDIT-> If you wanted to configure Samba:

Are you using Samba?  I imagine you are, have you edited the Samba configuration file?

Where your share equals "testshare" you will need something like:

```
[testshare]
comment = Public Share
path = /path/to/share/point
read only = no
browseable = yes
guest only = yes
guest ok = yes
```

Note that is a public share at a very basic level.  Here is a useful link I just borrowed:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide